# How to keep the values defined in `exec()` in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, exec, local-variables

I have 2 Python scripts:

**ScriptSmall.py:**

```
a=9
```

**ScriptBig.py:**

```
a=5
print(a)

f=open('ScriptSmall.py')
exec(f.read())
f.close

print(a)
```

When I run **ScriptBig.py** in the terminal as `python3 ScriptBig.py`, the terminal prints out:

```
$python3 ScriptBig.py
5
5
```

I would like it to print out `5` and then `9`. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you use `exec()`, it's just like if the code there were in the script. It doesn't have its own scope.

Comment: What's the point of executing `ScriptSmall.py` if you don't want to get its variable assignments? That's all it does.

Comment: Why are you using `exec()` instead of `import`? Then the variables will be scoped to the module name.

Comment: @Barmar this code *should* work though, since it is working with `globals`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That's the reason for the problem. There's only one global variable `a`, so when `ScriptSmall.py` assigns to it, it updates the variable in `ScriptBig.py` as well.

Comment: @Kasramvd There are no local variables in this script, it's all globals.

Comment: @Barmar No, it doesn't. Note, `ScriptSmall.py` *never runs*. It's basically a text-file which the second script loads as a string `"a = 9\n"` and executes. I ran this on my computer and it prints `5` and then `9`

Comment: @Stefano I cannot reproduce your output. I get 5 and 9. Are you **sure** this is exactly the code you are running? The *main problem I see is that you are using `exec` to begin with*, but I do not see the output you are describing, I see the output you expect.

Comment: @Barmar Yes but the answer is still there. `exec` has its own scope and changing an immutable variable inside its scope doesn't affect the global namespace.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Yes, you are right. My actual code is has one more nested call. I didn't add that one for sake of clarity but it seems that it resulted the opposite. I found my answer in the link that Kasramvd pointed out. Thank you all for your comments. I am fairly new in Python and they helped.